# GParted accidentally deleted my /dev/sdb partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo P50.

I have 2 SSDs on my laptop as follows:

- `/dev/sda` - 256GB, has both a Linux partition and a Windows partition
- `/dev/sdb` - 512GB, single FAT32 partition, used to store large data files (all of which are either unimportant or backed up elsewhere)

I wanted to move windows to `/dev/sdb` so that my Linux partition could take up all 256GB of `/dev/sda`. To do that, I first wanted to shrink my `/dev/sdb` "data storage" partition.

To shrink my `/dev/sdb` partition, I opened gGParted and used the "resize partition" operation to shrink my `/dev/sdb` partition to 128GB. GParted reported that it completed the operation successfully.

I closed GParted and reopened it.  When I reopened it, it reported that the size of my `/dev/sdb` partition was unchanged, and it was still taking up the entire 512GB of the drive. I did the "resize" operation again.  After doing the resize operation a second time, the partition table became corrupted.  GParted was no longer able to detect the file system.

Testdisk was not able to detect my fat32 filesystem either. fdisk reported 4 partitions of random sizes, suggesting that the partition table was corrupted.

I plan to shuffle around some important data in the future, and I want to know:

- What I did wrong
- Why this happened
- How can I recover my data? I'm willing to open a hex editor and pick through it by hand.
- How do I prevent this in the future?

Answer (score 3):

What I did wrong

First mistake was using FAT32 and assuming you could save larger files. FAT32 does not have a journal, to make recovery/repair easier and cannot save files over 4GB. It may say you saved it but only first 4GB saved.

When gparted said it worked but did not show it, you should have immediately stopped an investigated why. May have needed chkdsk which is really slow on FAT32 as no journal.

Why this happened

Not sure, usually gparted works, but often better to use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Then you do not blame Linux for corrupting a Windows file system.

How can I recover my data (I'm willing to open a hex editor and pick through it by hand)

You probably should use ddrescue or similar tools to image drive. Then you can use photorec which is part of testdisk to scan drive for anything that looks like a file. Since only one partition, you then could just try resetting partition table and see if chkdsk or dosfsck works.

How do I prevent this in the future?

I now like gpt as it has backup partition table over MBR(msdos), but Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt. Ubuntu can be UEFI or BIOS boot from gpt. I would suggest reinstalling Ubuntu rather than moving Windows. You then could move /home & data into new install easily before deleting old install. If you want a data partition for sharing data use NTFS.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion of using photorec.  I'm surprised that I didn't come across it as I was researching linux file recovery tools.  It does a very good job.